# Generating a PDF includes a white border on the downloaded PDF

Tags: puppeteer

A white border is added on my PDF when generated using Puppeteer.

Below is my Puppeteer PDF generate Code.

```
const pdf = await page.pdf({
            path: './pdf/white_border_3.pdf',
            printBackground: true,
            preferCSSPageSize: true,
            height: '800px',
            width: '650px',
            scale: 1,
            margin: {top: '0px',right: '0px',bottom: '0px',left: '0px'}
          })
```

Below is Output : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEPqp.png)

Comment: Have you found a workaround?

Comment: No, I haven't found a workaround.